# Docpad error: Error 15 (net::ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED): Error unknown

Tags: docpad

I have been running on some problems since the last update (6.38.1). docpad seems to be broken on macosx the command "**docpad run**" or "**docpad watch**" returns the error (on the browser)

```
Error 15 (net::ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED): Error unknown
```

when i try to access

```
http://localhost:9778
```

but "**docpad server**" works without problems, so maybe the error is the liverload module or other module for development... i'm not able to isolate this problem.

does anyone has the same problem and maybe a solution to share? i'm about to leave docpad because of this error :(

Comment: Do versions below v6.38 work for you?

Comment: i did a downgrade and no, the problem is still there. probably is because the site has lots of images... not completely sure. if you want i can provide access to the site git repo. another thing i have noticed. it seems that the error only happens on macosx (not 100% certain, but at least the site looks online and works), you can check the site on dospuntocero.cl

Comment: just tried with 6.37.1 and no luck either... :(

Comment: I'm having the exactly same problem.